# Table row colspan percentage not passing validator

Tags: html, html-table, w3c-validation

I'm generating some html tables and I want the first row to colspan *all* the other rows so this is what I did:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="100%">Table title</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The thing is I also want my site to be w3c valid:

```
Bad value 100% for attribute colspan on element td: Expected a digit but saw % instead.
```

I tryied with colspan="all", it doesn't work, I thought I could put a really high value like colspan=500 to make sure it's always colspan-ed, but seems a bit dirty and still not valid.

Is there a way to colspan every other rows and be w3c valid?

Comment: why don't you know how many columns are in the table?

Comment: Considering the architecture of my project it's a bit hard to know it. Plus i'd like to be as generic as possible. (but it's not impossible, if I have no other choice I'll count them)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the caption element. That is used to provide a title to your table and cover all the table columns.

```html
<table>
    <caption>Table title</caption>
    <tr>
        <td>Data cell</td>
        <td>Data cell</td>
        <td>Data cell</td>
    </tr>
    [...]
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect, forgot about that tag!

Answer (score 1):

1) W3 specs say the value must be an integer NUMBER. Percent definitely does NOT work.

> This attribute specifies the number of columns spanned by the current
>   cell. The default value of this attribute is one ("1"). The value zero
>   ("0") means that the cell spans all columns from the current column to
>   the last column of the column group (COLGROUP) in which the cell is
>   defined.

2) Firefox is the only browser that currently supports 0.

3) You can try a very large number but that may also get you into trouble with validators. Perhaps you should try using Javascript to set that attribute at run time when you DO know the number of columns in the table.